# p:push not working with atmosphere spring boot

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-boot, atmosphere

I am converting an existing application which was spring 3, PrimeFaces 5 into spring boot application.
Following are my main dependencies,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

My spring configuration for push servlet bean is ,

```
@Bean
ServletRegistrationBean pushServletRegistration(){
    ServletRegistrationBean pushServlet=new ServletRegistrationBean();
    Map<String, String> mapParams=new HashMap<>();
    mapParams.put("org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass", "org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache");
    pushServlet.setServlet(new PushServlet());
    pushServlet.setInitParameters(mapParams);
    pushServlet.addUrlMappings("/primepush/*");
    pushServlet.setName("Push Servlet");
    pushServlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
    pushServlet.setLoadOnStartup(100);
    return pushServlet;
}
```

Following is my push end point

```
@PushEndpoint("/event")
public class EventMapNotifyResource {

    @OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
    public Event onMessage(Event coordinate) {
        return coordinate;
    }
}
```

and I am getting the following while the application boots,

```
2016-03-22 14:49:48.539  INFO 70488 --- [  restartedMain] org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework   : Installed AtmosphereInterceptor @PushEndpoint Interceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
2016-03-22 14:49:48.546 ERROR 70488 --- [  restartedMain] org.primefaces.push.PushServlet          : No Annotated class using @PushEndpoint found. Push will not work.
2016-03-22 14:49:48.547  INFO 70488 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-03-22 14:49:48.554  INFO 70488 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.h.a.demo.CommandCentreApplication    : Started CommandCentreApplication in 9.702 seconds (JVM running for 10.386)
```

my push functionality is not working with following error,

And same code is working without spring boot using same versions of Atmosphere , JSF, primefaces

```
org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereMappingException: No AtmosphereHandler found. Make sure you define it inside WEB-INF/atmosphere.xml or annotate using @___Service
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:140) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:108) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:66) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2262) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:190) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:176) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Basically `@PushEndpoint` is not working with spring boot.

Comment: Better to also tag this 'atmosphere' since it is most likely not PrimeFaces related but Atmosphere/Springboot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I referred to a [git repository](https://github.com/jirkapinkas/sitemonitoring-production) and found this solution ,

```
    ServletRegistrationBean pushServlet = new ServletRegistrationBean(new PushServlet(), "/primepush/*");
    pushServlet.addInitParameter("org.atmosphere.annotation.packages", "org.primefaces.push");
    pushServlet.addInitParameter("org.atmosphere.cpr.packages", "com.acn.hps.aops.demo.map.service");
    pushServlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
    pushServlet.setLoadOnStartup(0);
    pushServlet.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
```

Its working for me.
Thanks

Comment: Thanx that worked great. For parameter org.atmosphere.cpr.packages you have to put your own package.